# Translation Editor doesn't show all string of different languages

Tags: android, android-studio

I write 4 string for testing and try to add other languages with translation editor but its not showing translation text of other language. Please find attached screenshot and help me!

[image: Translation Editor screenshot]

Comment: Did you write the translation but the editor does not show them?

Comment: you are supposed to fill-in those text by yourself. It won't translate strings for you

Answer (score 0):

I can see that in your project view you only have two string files (the default and the es one).

You can click on the "earth" icon to add another languages or create another sting file (for example *string-en.xml* for *EN*glish).

Please check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html#addlanguage) for further details.

And as Vlad answered, Android Studio won't translate strings for you.